# with data of 100 row and 53 col, i want to extract the columns name which contains only true and false as data from the csv file using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, numpy

reducntant  app     kite    jacker  reductant2
op1         true    FALSE   item    FALSE
op2         FALSE   true    item4   true
op3         true    FALSE   item2   true
op4         true    true    item4   true

this table is small respresentation of the large 100x53 data i have . How to extract only the names of the columns which has true and false data values?
I have around 53 columns and they are a combinations columns different column names,& different columns values but i m interested in only extracting columns that has true and false string data.
i used the below code thinking that , i can traverse the csv and extract columns name which has true and false only but it doesnt work. Any help is appreciated!

```
 for col_name in df.columns:
       if (df[col_name] =='True' and 'False'):
            print(col_name.tolist())
       else :
            print('none')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add a picture of the actual DataFrame and the result of `df.dtypes()`. maybe it's better to make a small example with just 3 or  4 columns.

Comment: I cant showcase the actual dataframe and the df.dtypes throws the TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable.

Comment: my bad, `df.dtypes` please. If you make a simple example, we can help you efficiently.

Comment: the csv file has boolean,object,float and int types. The data i need to extract are the boolean type  that is in the form of true and false only

Comment: Are you sure `Pandas` does not already convert your columns to boolean data type? In this case use `select_dtypes`. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
temp = (df.iloc[:,:]).isin(['true','false']).any()#returns a bool pd.Series True=> column contains only 'true' and 'false'
columns_to_drop = [] #column index to be dropped
for i in range(len(temp)):
    if t[i] == False:
        columns_to_drop.append(i)
        
df.drop(df.columns[columns_to_drop], axis = 1, inplace = True) #required data frame
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas infers automatically boolean columns, so the code below should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.select_dtypes(bool)
```

In the case of it doesn't work, you can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str)  # disable dtype detection
df = df.loc[:, df.isin(['false', 'true']).all()]  # take care of case
```

Comment: @user10057386. What's wrong with my answer? It doesn't work anymore?